# HTML5 geolocation: logic to get initial position as well as watchLocation?

Tags: html, geolocation

I'm using HTML geolocation and I'd like to achieve the following:

```
1. User arrives at page
2. User is asked to share location
3. When user says yes, Google Maps initialises and centres on their position
4. We add marker to map showing their position
5. (ongoing) As the user moves, the marker continues to move with them
```

I've implemented this as follows:

```
// Add a marker
function addMarker(loc) { // adds marker }
function setupMap(loc) { // initialise map and centre on user's position };
setUpMap(???????);
// Start watching user's position
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(addMarker);
```

So my question is: how can I get the initial position in order to set up the map?

I can see two options, both of which have flaws:

1. Call `setUpMap` from within `addMarker`, but then the map gets re-initialised each time the user moves, which is obviously inefficient.
2. Call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` before calling `watchLocation` - but then the user seems to get prompted twice for their location, which looks clunky.

Any better ideas?

Thanks everyone.

**UPDATE**

OK, it seems I haven't explained this well. My question is really: how do I get the user's location from watchPosition, as a one-off, so that I can initialise the map once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**3.** Call watchLocation in step two, i.e. to get initial location (the user therefore will only get prompted once)

Comment: Ah, that's what I don't understand - how do I get initial location from watchPosition? I see that I can call **a function** from watchposition, but it seems that function gets re-run each time the user moves, and I don't want to be re-initialising the map every time they move.

Comment: have a boolean flag e.g. IsPositionInitialised=false; and on the first run of watchPosition callback if !IsPositionInitialised, initialize map, else move the marker and set IsPositionInitialised to true. I think you should also check whether marker's moved outside map's boundaries to re-draw it if it has.

Comment: OK. I had thought of this but it seemed kinda crude, but if it is the best way... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Call this:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition
```

instead of this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

`watchPosition` function also initializes positions.

Comment: I am calling this (see question text). My question is: how can I initialise the map **once** from within watchPosition, without doing so again every few seconds? The success function within watchPosition seems to be called regularly, which obviously isn't what you want when setting up the map as a one-off.

Comment: @Richard `watchPosition()` does not initialize every seconds. It initializes when position data changes.

Comment: sure, but if someone's on mobile they're likely to be moving around, and you don't want to be re-initialising a map every time that happens.

Comment: I noticed that the initial position is accurate, then it moves to a position that is less accurate, and then back to the more accurate position. I'm wondering if the initial position is a cached position. Then it gets a "close" position (via some heuristic) and then refines that?